# discord.py problems with the checking

Tags: discord.py

im trying to do a trivial discord bot, but with a "helper" it reveals you letter by letter the answer, each "x" senconds, but the problem is i can't to send the answer till the help is fully displayed
in the image the problem is cleary visible

this is the whole code

```py
    await ctx.send(a) #question
    respuestas = b #answer
    #reveal
    string = respuestas[0]
    blanked_string = [x if x.isspace() else "-" for x in string]
    nonspace_indexes = [i for i, _ in enumerate(string)]
    random.shuffle(nonspace_indexes)
    for i in nonspace_indexes:
        blanked_string[i] = string[i]
        await ctx.send(''.join(blanked_string))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
    #checking
    def check(msg=discord.Message) -> True:
        return msg.content.lower() in respuestas and msg.channel == ctx.message.channel
    try:
        guess = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=6, check=check)
        return await ctx.send(f"{guess.author.mention} first")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("time over")


#problem
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlatG.png

note: im not trying to do a hangman
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
async def letters(response: str, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    blanked_string = [x if x.isspace() else "-" for x in response]
    nonspace_indexes = [i for i, _ in enumerate(response)]
    random.shuffle(nonspace_indexes)
    for i in nonspace_indexes:
        blanked_string[i] = response[i]
        await channel.send(''.join(blanked_string))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    

@client.command()
async def game(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send("Author of Python programming language...")
    response = "Guido van Rossum"
    letters_func = asyncio.create_task(letters(response, ctx.channel))
    try:
        player_response = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel, timeout=30)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        letters_func.cancel()
        await ctx.send("Time's up!")
    else:
        letters_func.cancel()
        if player_response.content == response:
            await ctx.send("Correct!")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Incorrect!")
```

Here is a possible resolution path for your problem. I took advantage of asyncio's presence to do this. You can test it, it works very well.
Be careful to adapt your response time to the length of your answer